# Sass linter with BEM - Class should be written in lowercase with hyphens

Tags: sass, atom-editor, bem, linter, sass-lint

The error I am getting is Class should be written in lowercase with hyphens

```
.video_wrapper {
  //styles
  &__controls {
  //more styles
```

Should I and can I suppress this error?

Answer (score 1):

See [class-name-format](https://github.com/sasstools/sass-lint/blob/master/docs/rules/class-name-format.md) property to change this rule.